# Is there a way to implicitly convert a TimeSpan to a TimeOnly?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-7.0, repodb

I have a SqlServer database has a Time column call StartTime.  My entity then has a TimeOnly property that is mapped to StartTime.

I then wish to retrieve this value using RepoDb as the ORM.

When I try this, an exception is thrown, as a Time column in Sql Server maps to a TimeSpan, not a TimeOnly.  If I just the Entity Property to a TimeSpan, then no exception is thrown.

The workaround is to manually cast it from Timespan to Timeonly.  For example:

```
//Mapped to Time data type.
public TimeSpan TimeOnlyTest {get;set;}

public TimeOnly MyTimeOnly
{
    get { return TimeOnly.FromTimeSpan(this.TimeOnlyTest); }
    set { this.TimeOnlyTest = value.ToTimeSpan(); }
}
```

This works, but I would like to enable an implicit conversion so this is not necessary.

This is the error message:

```
$exception  {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.TimeOnly'."}  System.InvalidCastException
```

Comment: I edited the question to make this more clear

Comment: By "implicit conversion" are you referring specifically to C#'s `implicit operator TOutput(TInput)`? If so, then no, because you can't define an `implicit operator` between two types unless you control the definition of at least 1 of those 1 types. It sounds like you want to configure your ORM to support `TimeOnly` - in which case see RepoDB's page on `TypeMap`: https://repodb.net/attribute/typemap

Comment: ...but it's still probably simpler to keep your code as-is (though you could make the `TimeSpan` property `private` and the `TimeOnly` property `public` (assuming your ORM supports mapping to `private` properties).

Comment: BTW, the code you've posted can't produce that exception message: `FromTimeSpan` and `ToTimeSpan()` won't cause an `InvalidCastException` (it only throws `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`).

Comment: It's not the manual cast using FromTimeSpan, and ToTimeSpan  that throws the exception, it is the implicit cast by the ORM.

Comment: Is `TypeMap` what you’re looking for?

Comment: I know nothing of RepoDb but I've checked the documentation and I think you might be looking for [Type Level Mapping](https://repodb.net/mapper/typemapper#type-level-mapping)

Comment: @ZoharPeled, Thank you.  I have tried, this but the same issue persists.